# jQuery deferred promises executing out of order?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, jquery-deferred

**EDIT: IMPORTANT NOTE this is using jQuery 1.7.2, and no it cannot be changed from this version**

I'm new to promises and trying to wrap my head around them. I'm trying to execute a series of functions in order, waiting for them to complete before creating some child views (this is in Backbone.js). Here's my code:

```
initialize: function () {
    console.log('AppView::initialized!');
    var _this = this;

    $.when( _this.processCookies() )
        .then( _this.loadAdScripts() )
        .then( _this.createChildViews() );
},

processCookies: function () {
    var def = $.Deferred();
    console.log('(1) PROCESS COOKIES');
    return def.resolve();
},


/**
 * Instantiates new instances of the child views.
 */
createChildViews: function () {
    var _this = this;
    console.log('(4) CREATING CHILD VIEWS');
},

loadAdScripts: function () {

    var _this = this,
        def = $.Deferred();

    $.when(
        _this.insertScript({
            name: 'example1',
            async: false,
            src: '//www.example.com/script1.js',
        }),
        _this.insertScript({
            is_mobile: is_mobile,
            name: 'example2',
            async: true,
            src: '//example.com/script2.js'
        })
    )
    .done(function () {
        console.log('(3) ALL SCRIPTS LOADED');
        def.resolve();
    });
},

insertScript: function (script) {
    var def = $.Deferred(),
        protocol = (document.location.protocol === 'https:' ? 'https:' : 'http:');

    // dont script 2 on mobile.
    if (script.name === 'example2' && script.is_mobile) {
        console.log('skipping script');
        return def.resolve();
    }

    var promise = $.ajax({
        dataType: 'script',
        cache: false,
        async: script.async,
        url: protocol + script.src,
    });

    promise.done( function () {
        console.log('(2) SINGLE SCRIPT LOADED');
        return def.resolve();
    });


},
```

So, the desired flow here is:

1. When the `processCookies()` function is completed,
2. execute `loadAdScripts` function
   2a. `insertScript()` fires, script 1 loads
   2b. `insertScript()` fires, script 2 loads
3. when BOTH scripts are finished, execute `createChildViews` function.

so, observing the `console.log()` placeholders in the code, I *expect* to see in my console:

```
'(1) PROCESS COOKIES'
'(2) SINGLE SCRIPT LOADED'
'(2) SINGLE SCRIPT LOADED'
'(3) ALL SCRIPTS LOADED'
'(4) CREATING CHILD VIEWS'
```

**however** what I *actually* see is:

```
'(1) PROCESS COOKIES'
'(3) ALL SCRIPTS LAODED'
'(4) CREATING CHILD VIEWS'
'(2) SINGLE SCRIPT LOADED'
'(2) SINGLE SCRIPT LOADED'
```

What is wrong with my promises, and why are they not executing in the expected order?

Comment: I'm not familiar with promises, but you are using ajax call here and that's asynchronous! Could be the reason why your calls are out of order. You can try adding the successful function to the ajax, and once successful, do next step. I see other function calls in there. Are those Asynchronous as well? You might want to look into callback functions if exist with that.

Comment: @bravekido promises are also asynchronous. `$.ajax` returns a promise. OP is fully aware of the asynchronous issue and is trying to organize timing of the order of callbacks

Comment: @bravekido yeah they are ajax calls, but I need to wait for them to complete (or fail) before executing rest of page, like charlieftl explained.

Comment: With old jQuery, you'll want to use `pipe` instead of `then`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$.when( _this.processCookies() )
        .then( _this.loadAdScripts() )
        .then( _this.createChildViews() );
```

appear to be calling `loadScripts()` , `createChildViews()` immediately, instead try referencing function names at `.then(_this.loadAdScripts)` callbacks .

`return def.resolve()` returns `jQuery.Deferred()` object , not jQuery promise object ; try adding `.promise()` after `.resolve()` to return jQuery promise object .

`jQuery.ajax()` returns jQuery promise object ; not necessary to create new jQuery `$.Deferred()` object, could return `$.ajax()`

```
initialize: function () {
    console.log('AppView::initialized!');
    var _this = this;

    $.when( _this.processCookies() )
        // reference function name, not invoked
        .then( _this.loadAdScripts )
        .then( _this.createChildViews );
},

processCookies: function () {
    // no asynchronous operations appear here, 
    // no need to include `$.Deferred()` or `.promise()` object
    // var def = $.Deferred();
    console.log('(1) PROCESS COOKIES');
    // return jQuery promise object, not deferred object
    // return def.resolve().promise();
},


/**
 * Instantiates new instances of the child views.
 */
createChildViews: function () {
    var _this = this;
    console.log('(4) CREATING CHILD VIEWS');
},

loadAdScripts: function () {

    //var _this = this,
    //    def = $.Deferred();

    return $.when(
        _this.insertScript({
            name: 'example1',
            async: false,
            src: '//www.example.com/script1.js',
        }),
        _this.insertScript({
            is_mobile: is_mobile,
            name: 'example2',
            async: true,
            src: '//example.com/script2.js'
        })
    )
    .done(function () {
        console.log('(3) ALL SCRIPTS LOADED');
        // def.resolve();
    });
},

insertScript: function (script) {
    // var def = $.Deferred(),
        protocol = (document.location.protocol === 'https:' ? 'https:' : 'http:');

    // dont script 2 on mobile.
    // if (script.name === 'example2' && script.is_mobile) {
    //    console.log('skipping script');
    //    return def.resolve().promise();
    // }

    var promise = script.name === 'example2' && script.is_mobile 
                  ? $.when() 
                  : $.ajax({
                      dataType: 'script',
                      cache: false,
                      async: script.async,
                      url: protocol + script.src,
                    });

    promise.done( function () {
        console.log('(2) SINGLE SCRIPT LOADED');
        // def.resolve();
    });    
},
```

---

> **EDIT: IMPORTANT NOTE this is using jQuery 1.7.2, and no it cannot be
>   changed from this version**

Edit, Updated

Expected order may not be possible using jQuery version 1.7.2 , without modifying source.

Appear to return expected order when using jQuery version 1.8+ , following update of [deferred.then](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then) ; see http://blog.jquery.com/2012/08/09/jquery-1-8-released/ , http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11010

1.8.0

```js
var dfd = {
    initialize: function () {
        console.log('AppView::initialized!');
        _this = dfd;

        $.when(_this.processCookies())
        // reference function name, not invoked
        .then(_this.loadAdScripts)
        .then(_this.createChildViews);
    },

    processCookies: function () {
        // no asynchronous operations appear here, 
        // no need to include `$.Deferred()` or `.promise()` object
        var def = $.Deferred(function (d) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                d.resolve('(1) PROCESS COOKIES')
            }, Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000));
        }).promise();
        def.then(function (msg) {
            console.log(msg);
        });
        return def.promise()
    },


    /**
     * Instantiates new instances of the child views.
     */
    createChildViews: function () {
        _this = dfd;
        console.log('(4) CREATING CHILD VIEWS');
    },

    loadAdScripts: function () {
        _this = dfd;
        return $.when.apply(_this, [_this.insertScript({
            name: 'example1',
            async: false,
            src: '//www.example.com/script1.js',
        }),
        _this.insertScript({
            is_mobile: true,
            name: 'example2',
            async: true,
            src: '//example.com/script2.js'
        })]).then(function () {
            console.log('(3) ALL SCRIPTS LOADED');
        })
    },

    insertScript: function (script) {
        // var def = $.Deferred(),
        protocol = (document.location.protocol === 'https:' ? 'https:' : 'http:');

        // dont script 2 on mobile.
        // if (script.name === 'example2' && script.is_mobile) {
        //    console.log('skipping script');
        //    return def.resolve();
        // }

        var promise = $.when( script.name === 'example2' && script.is_mobile ? $.Deferred(function (d) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                d.resolve('(2) skipping script', protocol + script.src)
            }, Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000))
        }).promise() : $.Deferred(function (d) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                d.resolve('(2) SINGLE SCRIPT LOADED', protocol + script.src)
            }, Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000))
        }).promise())
        
        return promise.then(function(msg) {
          console.log(msg)
        });
    }
};

dfd.initialize();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

1.72

```js
var dfd = {
    initialize: function () {
        console.log('AppView::initialized!');
        _this = dfd;

        $.when(_this.processCookies())
        // reference function name, not invoked
        .then(_this.loadAdScripts)
        .then(_this.createChildViews);
    },

    processCookies: function () {
        // no asynchronous operations appear here, 
        // no need to include `$.Deferred()` or `.promise()` object
        var def = $.Deferred(function (d) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                d.resolve('(1) PROCESS COOKIES')
            }, Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000));
        }).promise();
        def.then(function (msg) {
            console.log(msg);
        });
        return def.promise()
    },


    /**
     * Instantiates new instances of the child views.
     */
    createChildViews: function () {
        _this = dfd;
        console.log('(4) CREATING CHILD VIEWS');
    },

    loadAdScripts: function () {
        _this = dfd;
        return $.when.apply(_this, [_this.insertScript({
            name: 'example1',
            async: false,
            src: '//www.example.com/script1.js',
        }),
        _this.insertScript({
            is_mobile: true,
            name: 'example2',
            async: true,
            src: '//example.com/script2.js'
        })]).then(function () {
            console.log('(3) ALL SCRIPTS LOADED');
        })
    },

    insertScript: function (script) {
        // var def = $.Deferred(),
        protocol = (document.location.protocol === 'https:' ? 'https:' : 'http:');

        // dont script 2 on mobile.
        // if (script.name === 'example2' && script.is_mobile) {
        //    console.log('skipping script');
        //    return def.resolve();
        // }

        var promise = $.when( script.name === 'example2' && script.is_mobile ? $.Deferred(function (d) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                d.resolve('(2) skipping script', protocol + script.src)
            }, Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000))
        }).promise() : $.Deferred(function (d) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                d.resolve('(2) SINGLE SCRIPT LOADED', protocol + script.src)
            }, Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000))
        }).promise())
        
        return promise.then(function(msg) {
          console.log(msg)
        });
    }
};

dfd.initialize();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but...answer description? What's different? Is it just that the OP was calling the functions and passing the results to `.then()`? Don't make us compare your code line-by-line with the original.

Comment: I didn't downvote either, but a description would be nice :)

Comment: A code only `find the difference` answer with no explanation is not very high quality

Comment: Attempted to include descriptions of slight adjustments at comments , will update post

Comment: you may still be editing but current solution doesn't work

Comment: @Prefix Appear to return expected order when using jQuery version 1.8+ , after update of `.then()` http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/1tonoL6x/

Comment: @guest271314 interesting -- unfortunately due to some project reqs I cannot change the jQuery version :( Is this not possible with 1.7.2?

Comment: also, even with your 1.7.2 example, the child views function (4) is still firing before the script loading (2) (3). I need to make sure the scripts are loaded and parsed before creating the child views.

Comment: @Prefix See updated post . Moved `.then(_this.createChildViews)` to second chained `.then()` following `.insertScripts()` call ; appear to return expected order.